# Can't get mediarecorder to record at a high samplerate

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder

For a project i need to make an android app to record the sound amplitude at a high sample rate (10 samples per millisecond for instance)
For some reason the output of the app only gives back a sample every 10 milliseconds or less.

```
mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(96000);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);
```

I determined that by storing my timing and ampltitude data.

I stored my Amplitude data and my Timedata

```
final Runnable updateSoundLevel = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    if (SoundRecording==true){
    handler.postDelayed(this, 0);

    Amplitude = mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
    longTime= (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/1000000;
    int intTime=(int) longTime;
    listAmplitude.add(Amplitude);
    listTime.add(intTime);
    addEntry(intTime,Amplitude); // adding entry to graph
    ... rest of program
```

Comment: 96000Hz is 96 samples per millisecond. What is the actual sample rate of the data saved into `AudioSavePathInDevice`? And how, precisely, did you determine that?

Comment: @greeble31 I edited my answer to explain this

Answer (score 0):

I found the error,

The process to add an entry to my graph was too long.